# NullPointerException when using properties.load()

Tags: java, properties, nullpointerexception, fileinputstream

I have a little problem with Properties in Java, maybe you could help me.

In the following code i write my Properties object to XML:

```
global.storeToXML(new FileOutputStream(propertiesPath + SEPERATOR + GLOBAL + FILEEXTENSION), "");
```

This works fine and produces the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>test</comment>
<entry key="port">5001</entry>
<entry key="maxPlayers">1</entry>
</properties>
```

But if i try to load this file with the following code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(propertiesPath + SEPERATOR + GLOBAL + FILEEXTENSION);

if (fis != null)
 global.loadFromXML(fis);
```

the loadFromXML method throws a NullPointerException. According to the documentation of Properties this usually means that fis would be null, which it is obviously not.

I already tried the load() and store() methods (without XML) and get just the same error. When I try to read the file manually via fis it works fine.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: What is `global`? Probably `global` is null.

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is?

Comment: Put a check and see : `if (fis != null && global!=null)`!

Comment: Oh damn, now I am ashamed... forgot to initialize global at this point...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to initialize global. Sorry for the dumb question.